# meteor: searching data in collection

Tags: meteor

I have created `search` code, but the values cannot display. Can anyone help me?

This my code:

```
<template name="search">
  <form >
    <input type="text"  id="categories" />
    <button>Search</button>
  </form>
  <hr/>
  <h3></h3>
  <ol>
    {{#each profil}}
      <li>{{brand}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ol>
Template.search.events({
    "submit ": function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      Session.set("categories", $("#categories").val());
    }
  });

  Template.search.helpers({
    profil: function() {
      return Profil.find({
          categories: Session.get('categories'),
        });
    }
});
```

I'm not sure how to code in publish (server).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
Put this in search.html

```
<template name="search">
<form id="searchForm">
<input type="text"  id="categories" />
<button>Search</button>
</form>
<hr/>

<ol>
 {{#each profil}}
  <li>{{brand}}</li>
 {{/each}}
</ol>
</template>
```

This in search.js :

```
Template.search.events({
"submit #searchForm": function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  Session.set("categories", e.target.text.value);
}
});

Template.search.helpers({
profil: function() {
  return Profil.find({
      categories: Session.get('categories'),
    });
}
});
```

And make sure that "autopublish" package is added. This would do the trick!

Comment: i already remove autopublish.That why i need your help to code in publish (server).Thanks